# Where does OpenSUSE store journald logs?

Tags: opensuse, systemd-journald

I noticed there is no /var/log/journal in OpenSUSE Leap 15.1. Where does it store the journal logs?

Comment: Which release are you referring to?

Comment: @eblock Added to the OP now

Comment: The default is `/var/log/messages`, I just did a fresh install on a virtual machine without any custom settings.

Comment: @eblock That's not it I'm afraid. the journal contains more log entries than what's in the messages log

Comment: This is due to some services logging directly to systemd (journalctl) and others to syslog (/var/log/messages).